In its interference/disinformation campaigns of the US presidential election, has the PRC/CCP shown a preference for either Trump or Harris?
Based on an analysis of what a Harris or Trump administration will be like and what China's interests are, Wang, Hu, and Zhao (Foreign Policy, 2024-08-01) conclude:

overall, from a Chinese perspective, the China policies of a new Trump administration and a Harris administration will likely be strategically consistent. As presidents, both candidates would present challenges and disadvantages for China, and neither seems likely to want a major military conflict or to cut off all economic and societal contacts. Therefore, Beijing is unlikely to have a clear preference.

However, I am looking for a different sort of analysis:
Based on actual evidence (and ideally rigorous statistical analyses) from the PRC/CCP's interference/disinformation campaigns, does there seem to be any preference for either candidate?
(Such interference and disinformation campaigns may include but are not limited to fake/real stories in favor of one candidate and against another, emphasis of troll farms/bots, hacking.)

TBH I've not heard of the PRC bothering with an interference in this election, but I may just not be sufficiently informed. OTOH Iran and Russia are almost certainly backing different horses, despite what Putin says. Apparently China did something though https://thehill.com/opinion/campaign/4579674-chinas-magaflage-election-interference-is-about-more-than-2024/ but in 2023

https://www.wired.com/story/china-bad-at-disinformation/

I am from a country showing once openly preference for candidate A. Then candidate B won. The next cycle was quite terrible with the USA. I think, at least Taiwan should not ever take the risk, particularly until they are head-to-head. Simply not saying anything in the campaign, and then warmly welcoming the winner is the highest possible expected result. Probably nothing can piss off an USA president yet more, personally, if you campaign against him from overseas.

Recently Putin has shown preference for Kamala Harris, I think also that was a mistake - probably he has just trolled, but still it is not sure if it is understood by everyone.

No, there is no evidence of a strong preference for either candidate in recent foreign interference efforts. The objective is simply to boost partisan divisions and undermine popular legitimacy. While there isn't a great source addressing the question head-on, there is no reason to think they would be favoring either candidate.
The annual threat assessment published early in 2024 mentions that China released videos supporting both parties on TikTok during the 2020 mid-terms. It also discussed the more aggressive interference campaign by Iran which did not clearly support either party.
The closest thing to what the question is asking for was the research by ISP, also from early 2024, looking at China's so-called Spamoflage campaign.

the bulk of the content appears aimed at creating a sense of dismay over the state of America without any clear partisan bent. It focuses on issues like urban decay, the fentanyl crisis, dirty drinking water, police brutality, gun violence and crumbling infrastructure. These are not election-specific narratives and have been a significant feature of Spamouflage’s content over several years. While not explicitly linked to the election, however, this content clearly also feeds into the attempt to create a sense of dissatisfaction with the state of the country among voters, as well as potentially engendering a sense of chaos in the US amongst international audiences.

EDIT: Actually there's a very recent report from Graphika confirming the same for China/Spamoflage. They're denigrating both sides, not supporting one over the other.
And here is a July article from CBS News quoting experts who find that Russia is favoring Trump while Iran is trying to undermine him. There is some speculation that China may have preferred candidates in down-ballot races.

Yeah, best outcome for the CCP would be a civil war in the US, or some never ending Jan 6 as 2nd best. OTOH the Epoch Times is not abandoning Trump https://thediplomat.com/2024/08/donald-trumps-china-rhetoric-has-changed-the-epoch-times-support-for-him-has-not/

I wonder if Trump wouldn't a better actual outcome for China.  Among other reasons, when listening to defense podcasts (like War on the Rocks or
Horns of a Dilemma), the analysts frequently cite how their contacts @ US allies mistrust the return of T.  With T. at the helm, it seems the US would be way more isolated  in its dealings with China as very few countries trust him.  Same case was stated in by K. Rudd in Avoidable War :  T.'s "leadership" has weakened the alliance against China & it's not like Biden has been very friendly to China

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: OTOH Trump could go crazy and put more high tariffs on China, in the short run. Taiwan is important to the CCP but in the past decades they've been more restrained although sure that wasn't always the case. Mao used to fire artillery at the islands closest to the mainland etc. Also, some of the pundits discussing this point to Trump being much more of vengeful guy being a factor they consider in not interfering against his campaign specifically.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica BTW, interesting to read the diff messaging that Trump does on X vs TRUTH https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EriX_idQik4

Anyhow, he doesn't seem to focus on China much on TRUTH, but "will ‘build on his historic success’ of reducing America’s dependence on China through ‘universal baseline tariffs’. ‘The heart of my vision is a sweeping pro–American overhaul of our tax and trade policy to move from the Biden system that punishes domestic producers and rewards outsources to a system that rewards domestic production and taxes foreign companies and those who export American jobs." That's his campaign talking. China probably hopes he'll focus more on putting his domestic opponents in  jumpsuits, as the TRUTH goes.
